# How to add touchable opacity (touchableOpacity) for images in a flastlist to view them in full size?

Tags: react-native

This is my code for a displaying few images in a Flatlist, how can I add touchableOpacity to the images that when i press them, I can view the image in full size.

I also want to add some text as image description for the images. That when i press on the images, beside viewing images when sliding down the user can also read the description in **text** form for the image.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, FlatList,Dimensions} from "react-native";

export default function pic_flatlist() {
  const [images, setimages] = useState([
    {url:require("../assets/pic_one.jpg"),id:1},
    {url: require("../assets/pic_two.jpg"), id:2},
    {url: require("../assets/pic_three.jpg"),id: 3},
    {url: require("../assets/pic_four.jpg"),id: 4},
    {url: require("../assets/pic_five.jpg"),id: 5},
    {url: require("../assets/pic_six.jpg"),id: 6},
  ]);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={images}
      key={"2"}
      numColumns={2}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.homescreen}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Image
          source={item.url}
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.45,
            height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.55,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "white",
            resizeMode: "cover",
            marginVertical: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
            marginHorizontal: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  homescreen: {
    width:Dimensions.get('window').width,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

//rest of code

renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
          source={item.url}
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.45,
            height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.55,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "white",
            resizeMode: "cover",
            marginVertical: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
            marginHorizontal: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
```

In simple terms just import ToucableOpacity and add before and after  tag in your image tag.
This will make your only image clickable.
If you want flatlist to be clickable use TouchableOpacity before and after flatlist tag

Comment: This is not correct. 
I think you miss understood the question.

Comment: Ohkay, if I understand this correctly, it will be a kind of popup thing. You can try to call Modal component in react-native from TouchableOpacity. So when you click on image it will open Modal with image, text, description whatever you have written inside Modal component.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do, but is it possible to use the TouchableOpacity and onPress function for showing images without using the Modal component?
If you, can you please show me how?

Comment: I don't think you can use Image component inside onPress function. Modal component is the simple and easy way to present content above an enclosing view. Or Maybe you can use navigation for full screen (I haven't tried that though).

Answer (score 0):

```
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity  style={{
                width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.45,
                height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.55,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: "white",
                resizeMode: "cover",
                marginVertical: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
                marginHorizontal: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.02,
              }}
 onPress={() => alert("pressed")}>
            <Image
              source={item.url}
             
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
```

Comment: This is not correct. Using your method will not do anything at all except showing an alert.